# After notification button return to original activity

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, activity-manager

I wrote an app, that brings up a notification every certain time via an alarmIntent. The user clicks on the notification and gets into an activity. After doing something in this activity he should press a button to return to the original app he was in (like a browser, or the homescreen, etc.), before clicking on the notification.
My problem is, that the user always returns to the main activity of my application.
How can I change that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution finaly:
you need to add the Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASKS flag to the intent as explained in that question:
[Go back to previous screen on backbutton pressed after responding to notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20888013/go-back-to-previous-screen-on-backbutton-pressed-after-responding-to-notificatio)

Answer (score 2):

try adding this lines in your Activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: In the activity from the intent started or in the main activity of my application?

Comment: in the activity that is called from notification Click, hope it helps :)

Comment: it works, halfway :) I return to the homescreen when I press the back button. But is there a way to return to the previous application, too?

Comment: sorry for being late, just change the line intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); to  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT); just edited my answer after correctly understood what you needed

Answer (score 0):

Try `Activity.finish()` inside the button click listener function. This is similar to pressing the back button.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of Activity started by Notification : regular & special.
Regular Activity always return to Launcher or your previous activity.
Special Activity will return to your Application.

As your description, you should use Regular Activity and get PendingIntent by TaskStackBuilder, it will create an artificial back stack for notification activity.

for example :

```
PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
    stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And this is the document, you can find detail here.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Comment: I tried it, but I still go to the Home Screen and not to the previous App. Can you imagine why?

Comment: TaskStackBuilder add Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME to the action Intent, if you don't want return to home, TaskStackBuilder add Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_TASK_ON_HOME to the action Intent, if you don't want return to home, you should use PendingIntent.getActivity() instead of TaskStackBuilder: PendingIntent.getActivity(SecondActivity.this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);